# My IAR command line build fails with "Standard single tool failed to establish output file name"

Tags: iar

I need to build my IAR project using iarbuild.exe instead of the IDE. 
So I run:

```
iarbuild.exe myproject.ewp -make CONFIG -log all
```

and I get this:

```
         IAR Command Line Build Utility V8.2.1.5703
     Copyright 2002-2018 IAR Systems AB.

Building configuration: Nucleo_STM32F4 - RC_Q
Updating build tree...
Standard single tool failed to establish output file name.

Build aborted.


 ERROR, Command failed: make
```

The IDE can build without a problem. I dont know where I should start. Any help?

Comment: I am facing similar issue. Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: I found a solution to this. If you are using IAR's custom argument variable for Linker or Compiler output name, then you must pass custom variable file as an argument to iarbuild.exe. eg.

`iarbuild.exe myproject.ewp -make CONFIG -varfile myproject_Workspace.custom_argvars`